# Java Graphics Class Confusion

Tags: java, graphics

I'm sorry if this sounds somewhat vague, but I am having trouble articulating exactly what it is in Java's Graphics Class that confounds me.

What I am trying to do is simply draw a sequence of colored Strings. I have a method by which the Strings are parsed and ordered, but I cannot figure out how to convince Graphics to actually display the damn things once they're lined up.

I understand there is a Graphics method drawString(), apparently designed to accomplish this very task, but nowhere can I find a reasonable explanation of how to implement it. It seems to require a Graphics object to operate upon, but I cannot see how I am to define such an object. Java does not allow Graphics objects to be initialized, it seems, and I cannot find any clear explanation of why that is or how to get around it.

I have read numerous tutorials in which a very basic paint() method is used to demonstrate the functionality of drawString(), but every one I've encountered had the Strings hardcoded in and the method contained in a Graphics affiliated class, which will not serve my purposes. I cannot seem to even call the paint() method, at least not by any means I'm familiar with, and I have been unable to modify the parameters to accept, in addition to g, the variable Strings I wish to print.

I'd be very grateful for any clarification of how to implement a Graphics object. I have spent the last two hours wrestling with this problem and would love to put it behind me.

I'm getting a nullpointerexception at the setColor line. I have defined blue and red as colors earlier in the code.

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
Graphics g = c.getGraphics();
if (bool1) g.setColor(blue);
else g.setColor(red);
g.drawString(tval, x, y);
```

Comment: An example. Create a canvas(can be any swing component). Get the Canvas' graphics. call drawstring method. Done. If you want to change font, call changefont.

Comment: What media are you trying to draw these strings on? An image? JFrame? something else? The Graphics class is an abstract class and for your knowledge level you wouldn't be creating or implementing the Graphics class directly, more accessing one that is created through other means.

Comment: I tried creating a Canvas and taking the graphics from that, but it still seems to think g doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not consciously using any medium, which I'd guess is part of my problem. How does one correctly install a JFrame?

Comment: Continuing from my comment under MadProgrammer's answer below, overriding a parent class' method in a child class does exactly what it seems to, it overrides the method. In order to retain the functionality of a method and add more, you call the parent method of the method you're overriding before the extra functionality of your custom, overridden method. If you override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, you call `super.paintComponent(g)` and then add any functionality you want to the class. You shouldn't directly call `paintComponent`, you should just call the `repaint()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

`Graphics` is an abstract concept representing some kind of output, screen, image, printer.

In order to render content, you must first obtain an instance of the `Graphics` context of your intended output.

For screen and printer, this is provided by the system, so you need to link into the various paint chains.

For screen, the simplest is to override `paintComponent` of a component that extends from `JComponent` (typically `JPanel`)

Comment: This is embarrassing, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by override paintComponent of a component that extends from JComponent. paintComponent is a method in Graphics, I believe, but I do not understand what it does or how a component would be defined.

Comment: No, it's not. paintComponent is a method of JComponent (typically we recommend JPanel as a starting point). When added to a displayable container (like a frame/window), the paint subsystem will call this method (in directly) when it wants you to repaint the contents of the component. Read the tutorial

Comment: Every class in Java extends the `Object` class. Some classes extend other classes. A `JComponent` class extends the `java.awt.Container` class. The `Container` class extends the `java.awt.Component` class, and the `Component` class extends the `object` class. Each class that extends a parent class is called a child class or a subclass. Since `JPanel` is a subclass of `JComponent`, it has inherited the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` from it. There are more subclasses, and you can view them in the Java docs under "Direct known subclasses"

Comment: @bibliopheal If you're really invested, take a lookat at [Painting in Swing and AWT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)